# how to check NSString format from UIPasteBoard

Tags: ios, nsstring, uipasteboard

I am allowing the user to copy a registration key from my website, the NSStirng is then saved to the clipboard and when the application opens with the registration dialog I check the clipboard right away using this code -

```
NSString *registrationCode = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
```

Now that I have the value from the pasteboard I want to check its format.. which should be something like **AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA** so in essance No numbers, no spaces (including at the front and end), no lower case, no special characters... just uppercase characters. How could I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this in your code:

```
NSCharacterSet * everythingThatsAllowedSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-"];
NSCharacterSet * characterSetFromRegistrationCode = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: registrationCode];

if([everythingThatsAllowedSet isSupersetOfSet: characterSetFromRegistrationCode ] == YES)
    NSLog( @"this is a valid registration code");
else
{
    // if there are any characters in the registration code that aren't members of
    // the everythingAllowed set, the "isSupersetOfSet" test will fail
    NSLog( @"this has invalid characters");
}
```

Comment: perfect that worded nice.. Now I am going to check figure out who to check the hyphens are in the right place. that way i know for sure there is some type of registration code in my pasteboard.